# Django rest_framework dynamic selecting other objects

Tags: sql, django, filter, django-rest-framework

i want to create an Api for an order system. I have Ingredients and Products, both have categories which have to match if you want to combine them. So if a user selects a Pizza how can I only load in the ingredients which are available for Pizza, so the user cant select pasta as a Topping on his Pizza.
[So if the User selects a Product pizza in extra and extraWo only the ingredients should show up, which are available for pizza](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1rLC.png)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the API structure.
For example:

```
[
  {
    "Crust": "NORMAL",
    "Flavor": "BEEF-NORMAL",
    "Order_ID": 1,
    "Size": "M",
    "Table_No": 1,
    "Timestamp": "2018-12-12T13:42:13.704148+00:00"
  },
  {
    "Crust": "THIN",
    "Flavor": "CHEESE",
    "Order_ID": 2,
    "Size": "S",
    "Table_No": 5,
    "Timestamp": "2018-12-12T13:42:13.704148+00:00"
  },
  {
    "Crust": "NORMAL",
    "Flavor": "CHICKEN-FAJITA",
    "Order_ID": 3,
    "Size": "L",
    "Table_No": 3,
    "Timestamp": "2018-12-12T13:42:13.720690+00:00"
  }
]
```

Each pizza would be unique so foo[1]["Crust"] will give you "Normal". Add logic like checking the availability. Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield

For example do:

```
object.filter(pizza__normal='available')
```